# How do I know if a WebBrowser has finished loading a page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a piece of software, where I have created a WebBrowser. I can't figure out how you can check if the WebBrowser has finished loading.

It would be awesome if it could run a specific function when it finishes loading.

Comment: Thank you. You guys are so nice and helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using [`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use [the `DocumentCompleted` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, event) => DoSomething();
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx) is a great resource, which should be your first port of call when wondering about Microsoft APIs like this.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume you can use the [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Occurs when the WebBrowser control finishes loading a document.